# How to prevent running AfterSaveCallback on save

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to prevent running AfterSaveCallback on save on certain conditions `(say AfterSaveCallback<Foo>)`. We would like to avoid triggering `AfterSaveCallback` even when its present and registered. How to achieve this?

Refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/event/AfterSaveCallback.html

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Spring Data does not provide such functionality out-of-the-box, but you can probably achieve the desired behavior by implementing it on your own.

The `AfterSaveCallback` callback is invoked by the method [`maybeCallbackAfterSave`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/7582617a263a732f10ced36968dae265acb094db/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/AbstractElasticsearchTemplate.java#L797-L804) defined in `AbstractElasticsearchTemplate`:

```java
protected <T> T maybeCallbackAfterSave(T entity, IndexCoordinates index) {

  if (entityCallbacks != null) {
    return entityCallbacks.callback(AfterSaveCallback.class, entity, index);
  }

  return entity;
}
```

The idea is to provide a custom implementation for this method by extending [`ElasticsearchRestTemplate`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/7582617a263a732f10ced36968dae265acb094db/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java#L95). For instance:

```java
public class CustomElasticsearchRestTemplate extends ElasticsearchRestTemplate {

  public CustomElasticsearchRestTemplate(RestHighLevelClient client) {
    super(client);
  }

  public CustomElasticsearchRestTemplate(RestHighLevelClient client, ElasticsearchConverter elasticsearchConverter) {
    super(client, elasticsearchConverter);
  }

  @Override
  protected <T> T maybeCallbackAfterSave(T entity, IndexCoordinates index) {
    // compute as necessary
    boolean shouldSkipCallback = ...; 
    // if the conditions are met for the callback not to be applied,
    // just return the entity
    if (shouldSkipCallback) {
      return entity;
    }
  
    // else, proceed with the default implementation
    return super.maybeCallbackAfterSave(entity);
  }
}
```

Depending on the use case an anonymous class that overwrites `maybeCallbackAfterSave` will be suitable as well.

Then, use this custom `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` on its own or register it as the application default in the way you consider appropriate, for example, by extending [`AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/7582617a263a732f10ced36968dae265acb094db/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/config/AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration.java) - see [this great article](https://spinscale.de/posts/2020-08-06-introduction-into-spring-data-elasticsearch.html) - or by providing your own configuration directly - see [this for an example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-elasticsearch-tutorial).

The solution has a drawback, which is dealing with the generic `T entity` argument. For that purpose it may be of help and we can take as reference the code defined in `DefaultEntityCallbacks` defined for the [callback processing](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/fd586ebfdf9b828f0e31f79c7c032722ff4f8a9b/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mapping/callback/DefaultEntityCallbacks.java#L62-L92), especially this lines:

```java
Class<T> entityType = (Class<T>) (entity != null ? ClassUtils.getUserClass(entity.getClass())
                : callbackDiscoverer.resolveDeclaredEntityType(callbackType).getRawClass());
```

As you can see they use the [functionality implemented](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/fd586ebfdf9b828f0e31f79c7c032722ff4f8a9b/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/util/ProxyUtils.java#L52-L66) in `ClassUtils` in order to detect the actual class type.

Maybe you can take advantage of this knowledge and do something similar to the following code to determine if the callback should be or not applied:

```java
// Determine the class using one Spring magic
Class<T> entityType = (Class<T>) 
ClassUtils.getUserClass(entity.getClass());
// Then, compare with the appropriate types that should be excluded
boolean shouldSkipCallback = entityType.isAssignableFrom(Foo.class);
```

As an alternative, you can provide the class of the parameterized type `T` information to your `AfterSaveCallback<T>` implementation: this will allow you to determine whether the callback should or not applied based on the concrete class upon the `onAfterSave` method invocation.